# Cascading custom filter on ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to create a cascading filter on ActiveAdmin, and I am not quite sure how to go about it.

I have three models that have successive belongs_to/has_many relationships, e.g. A has many B's, and B has many C's.

I can create three filters like the following, and they work, but what I want to do is to limit B collection based on choice in A.

```
  filter :b_a_name, :as => :select, :collection => A.map(&:name)
  filter :b_name, :as => :select, :collection => B.map(&:name)
  filter :year
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this on ActiveAdmin?

Thank for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something like this using javascript, i.e.

- Listen to the change event on `b_a_name`
- Make an ajax request to an endpoint with the selection in `b_a_name` with
- Return an JSON array of the corresponding options for `b_name` in your success callback
- Replace the select options for `b_name` with options in array